# cant assign to function call

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I dont understand why this is happening.. It is not happening with anyone else I know.... Here is my code so far

```
# creating a string which will be our main sentence
string = input("Please enter a sentence.\n")
str(string)
# creates a list and then splits the string up and puts all the parts into a list
stringlist = []
string.lower()
string = string.split()
stringlist.append(string)

# prints the list to check for any errors during splitting
print(stringlist)

find = input("Which word would you like to find?\n")

while find in stringlist:
    index = stringlist.index(find)
    stringlist(index) = ""
    indexpositions.append(str(index + 1))
```

What I am trying to do is to find a word in a sentence and find all the indexes of it.

Comment: Why *what* is happening?

Comment: What does "can't assign" mean? Are you getting an error? If so, please edit the question and include the error.

Comment: Your code is _full_ of problems. Spend some time with the [official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/index.html).

Comment: BTW, your `while` is completely nonsensical. There are tons of better options to do whatever you're trying to do, but without knowing what the goal is exactly it's hard to recommend anything specific. Once you have working code, post it to http://codereview.stackexchange.com for help.

Comment: @deceze if you could read the title of the post you would understand the error i am getting...

Comment: Please always provide **a full, verbatim error message**, including line numbers they refer to. Yes, you briefly mentioned some problem in the title, but the body of the post should certainly expand on that.

Answer (score 3):

You're using the wrong parentheses to index `stringlist`. You should do `stringlist[index]=""`

Answer (score 2):

**List of problems I could find**

1. In Python, you need to use `[]` access the elements of a list. So you need to change your code to

   ```
   stringlist[index] = ""
   indexpositions.append(str[index + 1])
   ```
2. Apart from that,

   ```
   str(string)
   ...
   string.lower()
   ```

   are NOOPs. First line simply converts the `string` to a string object and discards it immediately and the second simply converts the string to lower case string and returns a new string object and that is also ignored. Probably you meant

   ```
   string = str(string)
   ...
   string = string.lower()
   ```

   Also, the `str(string)` part is not necessary, because `input` function returns a string object only.
3. Another problem is, [`string.find`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.find), returns `-1` if the item is not found in the list. In Python sequences can have negative indexes. So, you may want to be aware of that case as well.

So your code can be written like this

```
stringlist = input("Please enter a sentence.\n").lower().split()
```